# How to include canvas-datagrid in Angular 4

Tags: angular

I am trying to include the following library in my Angular 4 project but am having trouble doing so:-

https://github.com/TonyGermaneri/canvas-datagrid

I have ran:-

```
npm install canvas-datagrid
```

But when I try to use the following code in my ts file:-

```
<canvas-datagrid class="myGridStyle" data="data can go here too">[
{"col1": "row 1 column 1", "col2": "row 1 column 2", "col3": "row 1 
column 3"},
{"col1": "row 2 column 1", "col2": "row 2 column 2", "col3": "row 2 
column 3"}
]</canvas-datagrid>
```

I get the error:-

```
Invalid ICU message. Missing '}'
```

What steps would I need to do to use this in my angular 4 project as the documentation doesn't seem to include angular in it?

Answer (score 2):

I tested with Angular 7.2.

In app.component.ts:

```
import * as canvasDatagrid from 'canvas-datagrid';

//to create grid
var grid = canvasDatagrid({
      parentNode: document.getElementById('gridctr'),
      data: []
    });

//then set test data
grid.data = [
    {col1: 'foo', col2: 0, col3: 'a'},
    {col1: 'bar', col2: 1, col3: 'b'},
    {col1: 'baz', col2: 2, col3: 'c'}
];
```

In app.component.html, you should have a container for the grid accordingly:
    < div id="gridctr" >< / div >

That is it.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the npm package `canvas-datagrid`, I started with including the library in my component:

```
import * as canvasDatagrid from 'canvas-datagrid';
```

Then in my html file I added the template:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
```

And the following lines of codes I added in the ngOnInit function:

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.grid = canvasDatagrid({
  parentNode: 
 document.getElementById('grid'),
  data: [],
  schema: [
    {
      name: 'Time'
    },
    {
      name: 'Message' 
    } 
   ]
 });
 this.grid.style.height = 'calc(100vh - 
 229px)';
 this.grid.style.width = '100%';
 this.addData();
}
```

In the above code I have initialized the data for the grid as empty array. 
So for the initialization of the array I have written the below lines:

```
addData(){
 let data= [];  
 for(let i =0;i<1000;i++){
 data.push({'Time' : new Date() , 
'Message' : 'HELLO' );
  }
 this.grid.data 
 =this.grid.data.concat(data);
}
```